# can anyone please tell me weblogic 10.3.6 version is compatible with java 1.4 or not. Does it supports jdk1.6 onwards?

Tags: java, weblogic

I am upgrading my weblogic server 8 to weblogic 10.3.6. Web Application over weblogic uses java 1.4 . do the  java 1.4 application are supported over weblogic 10.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not with Java 1.4 since it is too old.

As you can see in this certification matrix Weblogic 10.3.6 is only compatible with Java 1.6+:

[WL11g Cert Matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/downloads/fmw-11gr1certmatrix.xls)

Answer (score 0):

java 1.4 will run on a java 1.6, however you may face other problems if you are using WLS 8 classes.

it may help.: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13754/toc.htm